# vb.net get links from a webbrowser (not image link)

Tags: vb.net

When I put my cursor on my webbrowser, I would like to get the link of the webpage ("/theURLiWANT.htm"). My probem is that I only get the link of the source of the image (https://www.urlimage.jpg)...

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a class="class1" href= "/theURLiWANT.htm/">
<img class="jsfh" src="https://www.urlimage.jpg">
</a>
```

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        htmlDocument1 = WebBrowser1.Document
        AddHandler htmlDocument1.MouseOver, AddressOf Me.DisplayLinks
    End Sub
    Public Sub DisplaLinks(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEAventArgs)
        TextBox1.Text = e.ToElement.GetAttribute("href")
    End Sub
```

Any idea to get the link : "/theURLiWANT.htm" in my textbox when I put the cursor on the image?

Thanks

Comment: @jmcilhinney 3 hours I m on this probem... I searched everywhere on the Internet, but nothing work.

Comment: @jmcilhinney TextBox1.Text = e.ToElement.parent.GetAttribute("href") thanks to have put me on tracks